# Как выполнять слияние очень больших массивов и избежать Memory error?

Tags: python-3.x, memory, pandas, dataframe

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно слить большие фреймы? У меня есть 3 датафрейма:

df:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3247237 entries, 0 to 3431773
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Name        object
Adress      object
Passport    object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 99.1+ MB
```

df1:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2164087 entries, 0 to 3118499
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Name     object
SNILS    object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 49.5+ MB
```

df2:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 4922588 entries, 0 to 4937703
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Number    object
Name      object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 112.7+ MB
```

Моя задача объединить все три фрейма в один по столбцу Name. При попытке использовать метод merge хотя бы для двух из них я получаю ошибку Memory Error:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, on='Name')
```

> MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 merged = df1.merge(df2, on='Name')

Comment: Сколько же у вас памяти (RAM) если вы получаете `MemoryError` для таких маленьких DFs?

Comment: @MaxU, юзабельных 7,90 Гб

Comment: Очень странно! У вас весь стек софта 64-битный?

Comment: Операционка и Анаконда точно 64 бит. Я смотрю в процессах, у меня на Python уходит 3,5 Гб памяти

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** пример `cartesian product`:

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]:
    name addr
0  name1   a1
1  name1   a2
2  name2   a3
3  name3   a4
4  name3   a5
5  name4   a6

In [26]: df1
Out[26]:
    name  number
0  name1       1
1  name1       2
2  name1       3
3  name5       4

In [27]: df.merge(df1, on='name')
Out[27]:
    name addr  number
0  name1   a1       1
1  name1   a1       2
2  name1   a1       3
3  name1   a2       1
4  name1   a2       2
5  name1   a2       3
```

---

Можно попробовать так:

```
df['SNILS'] = df['Name'].map(df1.set_index('Name')['SNILS'])
df['Number'] = df['Name'].map(df2.set_index('Name')['Number'])
```

`.map()` - удобно использовать если нам нужно добавить только один столбец из другого DF

Comment: если я так делаю, то получаю ошибку "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

Comment: @DenisNovik, теперь понятно почему у вас `MemoryError`. Если у вас дублируются имена то `merge` возвращает `декартово произведение (`cartesian product`)

Comment: да, здесь идет объединение "многие ко многим". А если сделать append и удалить дубликаты по Name?

Comment: это можно, но что вы получите на выходе? Я не знаю как однозначно (правильно) склеить фреймы по столцу с дупликатами... :(

Comment: спасибо. Буду экспериментировать)